# When will NSURLConnection decompress a compressed resource?

Tags: compression, streaming, zip, gzip, afnetworking

I've read how `NSURLConnection` will automatically decompress a compressed (zipped) resource, however I can not find Apple documentation or official word anywhere that specifies the logic that defines when this decompression occurs. I'm also curious to know how this would relate to streamed data.

**The Problem**

I have a server that streams files to my app using a chunked encoding, I believe. This is a WCF service. Incidentally, we're going with streaming because it should alleviate server load during high use and also because our files are going to be very large (100's of MB). The files could be compressed or uncompressed. I think in my case because we're streaming the data, the `Content-Encoding` header is not available, nor is `Content-Length`. I only see `"Transfer-Encoding" = Identity` in my response.

I am using the `AFNetworking` library to write these files to disk with `AFHTTPRequestOperation`'s `inputStream` and `outputStream`. I have also tried using `AFDownloadRequestOperation` as well with similar results.

Now, the `AFNetworking` docs state that compressed files will automatically be decompressed (via `NSURLConnection`, I believe) after download and this is not happening. I write them to my documents directory, with no problems. Yet they are still zipped. I can unzip them manually, as well. So the file is not corrupted. Do they not auto-unzip because I'm streaming the data and because `Content-Encoding` is not specified?

**What I'd like to know:**

1. Why are my compressed files not decompressing automatically? Is it because of streaming? I know I could use another library to decompress afterward, but I'd like to avoid that if possible.
2. When exactly does `NSURLConnection` know when to decompress a downloaded file, automatically? I can't find this in the docs anywhere. Is this tied to a header value?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`NSURLConnection` will decompress automatically when the appropriate `Content-Encoding` (e.g. `gzip`) is available in the response header. That's down to your server to arrange.